# Merge 2 dataframes with similar time indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes, `ts1` and `ts2`. The data structure looks like this:

```
    Date    Close
0   2004-08-05  0.0
1   2004-08-06  -155.0
2   2004-08-09  -140.0
3   2004-08-10  -2.0
4   2004-08-11  -24.0
```

Both have a `Date` and `Close` column. It possible that some dates are in ts1 but not in ts2 (and vice versa).

I would like to create a dataframe, `ts_merged`, that looks like this:

```
    Date        Close_TS1   Close_TS2
0   2004-08-05  0.0         1
1   2004-08-06  -155.0      133
2   2004-08-09  -140.0      4
3   2004-08-10  -2.0        2
4   2004-08-11  -24.0       2
```

I'd like a dataframe with **only** the Dates that are present in both `ts1` and `ts2`.

For the comparison I've tried `ts1.Date[ts1.Date == ts2.Date]`, and it doesnt work. For the merging, I've tried `.merge()` but it just merge everything in a unique Close column.

How can I do this?

Comment: `pd.merge(ts1, ts2, on="Date", how="inner")` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass how='inner' to the merge function. This will tell the merge function to do an inner join which will only keep keys found in both Data Frames.

```
ts_merged=ts1.merge(
    ts2, on='Date', how='inner', suffixes=('_TS1','_TS2')
)
```

Comment: `inner` is default, you actually dont have to pass it. :)